# WordPress theme-options page loads blank

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a redesign of my clients website through the CMS wordpress.
They want to keep the same theme, so I would need to make some changes to the basic theme options etc.

Every time I try to open the theme_options page it loads a blank page. A completely white screen, and by inspecting I can see that there is NO html what-so-ever loaded. not even the wordpress frame.

After this accident happened, I have tried to update all their plug-ins without any luck, and I have tried to deactivate the plug-ins without any luck.

Comment: Sounds like a php error, have you checked the error log? and/or enabled error logging?

Comment: Blank page is most likely a PHP error. Enable error reporting on your server (or wp-config.php) and you'll get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to your wp-config.php.

Comment: How would WP-DEBUG work @Sebastien ?

Comment: It's supposed to display PHP errors on your pages. Also try to enable 'on screen' errors in your PHP server. For example, I'm using MAMP PRO so I had to activate Xdebug and choose to display errors on the screens.

Comment: We couldn't get it fixed, so we ended up reinstalling the entire theme.. :S